# MySQL Limit joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `Category` and `Question` with one to many relationship tables, I want to 
have 3 random categories with 3 random questions in each. How to do it in one query?

```
Category
id
title

Question
id
title
cat_id
```

Sample output:

```
 cat_id title ques_id title cat_id
 4      Math  1       1+1?   1
 4      Math  3       2*5?   1
 4      Math  5       3*5?   1
 12     Hist  1       Who.   12
 12     Hist  2       blah   12
 12     Hist  5       blah   12
 15     Phys  1       m=.    15
 15     Phys  3       blah   15
 15     Phys  4       blah   15
```

Comment: provide sample data as well, with input/output

Comment: I have provided sample output, input would be large. Suppose thera are 10-20 categories and 100-1000 questions in each

Comment: want random records?

Comment: yes, 3 random categories and 3 random questions in each

Comment: Does MySQL support LIMIT in sub-queries?

Comment: Yes, it support Limit in sub-queries.

Comment: @MuratMustafin are you want the join on `Category.id = question.cat_id`. It confilct on first 3 record of your data set. I am confused

Comment: @MuratMustafin Are You want to use this result set on php interface or only for mysql shell  query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can live with the answer as 3 rows instead of 9, the easiest way is:

```
select c.*,
       substring_index(group_concat(q.id order by rand()), ',', 3) as question_ids
from category c join
     question q
     on c.id = q.cat_id
group by c.id
order by rand();
```

Otherwise, you can do this using variables:

```
select cq.*
from (select c.*, q.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = c.id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := c.id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select c.*
            from category c
            order by rand()
            limit 3
           ) c join
           question q
           on c.id = q.cat_id cross join
           (select @c := 0, @rn := 0) params
      order by c.id, rand()
     ) cq
where rn <= 3;
```

Of course, you should select the columns you actually need rather than using `*`.